# Locating a schema that owns a role

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, role, permissions

Let's say we've logged on under the A schema.

I am able to execute the following statement

```
grant select on wph_pden to LANDING_R;
```

However, the LANDING_R object can not be located in the schema A. It is absent from all the system tables and views.

How do I find out which schema owns the LANDING_R (which I know is a role, not user)???

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you're saying. Roles don't belong to schemas. Are you asking how to find what users were granted that role?

Comment: Is there a way to find out which user created a particular role?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39321/do-roles-have-an-owner-in-oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roles are not owned, but granted to users:

```
select grantee from dba_role_privs where granted_role = 'LANDING_R';
```

Object privileges granted to LANDING_R:

```
select * from dba_tab_privs where grantee = 'LANDING_R';
```

System privileges granted to the LANDING_R:

```
select * from dba_sys_privs where grantee = 'LANDING_R';
```

Comment: Is there a way to find out which user created a particular role?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39321/do-roles-have-an-owner-in-oracle